# Comma use in complex title

Tags: commas, quotes, titles

> This, as put forth by Marc Cyr in his essay titled “Randall Jarrell’s Answerable Style: Revision of Elegy in ‘The Death of the Ball Turret Gunner[,]’[,]” is likely Jarrell’s intent.

Where should the comma go in this sentence? I'm confused as the title being referenced references another title. Please pardon the length and redundancy; I'm not a fan of it either.

Comment: It's is a style matter, and different guides will give different advice regarding whether or when to place the comma after quotation marks. But presumably it should go before or after the closing of *both* sets of quotation marks in this instance. I like it after, as logically the quotation marks are part of the parenthetical element being set off by commas. But many style guides (American, mostly?) will disagree, for whatever arbitrary reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the comma after the word, before either of the quotation closing marks. Just like a period would be placed.